# Update table with left join where right table has multiple rows

Tags: mysql

I am trying to understand MySQLs behaviour when we do an update A left join B and there are multiple records joining from B.

Below is the example.

```
Table A:
id val
1  100

Table B:
id val
1  -100
1  -200
```

I run the below update

```
update a1 left join b1
on a1.id = b1.id
set a1.val = b1.val;
```

Table A now becomes:

```
Table A:
id val
1  -100
```

Here is the fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/da44db/1

In this case MySQL updates the value as the first value it gets from `a1 left join b1`
Why is it like this? Why did the value not become -200 instead?

Comment: This is expected behavour ' Each matching row is updated once, even if it matches the conditions multiple times' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html. If you want a specific row from table5 then you have to code for it - nb 'For multiple-table syntax, ORDER BY and LIMIT cannot be used.'